# Plot animated 2D mesh using matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I need to create a function to plot an animated 2D finite element using ***Python 3.5 + Matplotlib***. Basically, I have the nodes coordinates and their connectivity and a matrix of the nodal values at different time instants:

*values[i, j]: is the nodal value of the i-th node at the j-th time instant.*

I have found many examples online (such as [in here](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.2/examples/animation/index.html)), but none of them really helped me with my problem.

Here is the code that I made. It plots the mesh for a single time instant:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
#---
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection
from matplotlib import animation as animation
#---

nelements    = 32
nodesperside = 5
nnodes       = nodesperside*nodesperside
(xmin, xmax) = (0.0, 1.0)
(ymin, ymax) = (0.0, 1.0)
ntimes       = 10

x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, nodesperside)
y = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, nodesperside)

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)

xc = np.reshape(xx, (nnodes, ))
yc = np.reshape(yy, (nnodes, ))

nodenum = np.linspace(0,  nnodes - 1, nnodes)

coord       = np.zeros((nnodes, 3))
coord[:, 0] = nodenum
coord[:, 1] = xc
coord[:, 2] = yc

#---
# Conectividade global:
connect = np.zeros((nelements, 4), dtype = 'int')
connect[:, 0] = np.ones((nelements))
connect[ 0, 1: 4] = np.array([0, 1, 6])
connect[ 1, 1: 4] = np.array([1, 2, 7])
connect[ 2, 1: 4] = np.array([2, 3, 8])
connect[ 3, 1: 4] = np.array([3, 4, 9])
connect[ 4, 1: 4] = np.array([0, 6, 5])
connect[ 5, 1: 4] = np.array([1, 7, 6])
connect[ 6, 1: 4] = np.array([2, 8, 7])
connect[ 7, 1: 4] = np.array([3, 9, 8])
connect[ 8, 1: 4] = np.array([5, 6, 11])
connect[ 9, 1: 4] = np.array([6, 7, 12])
connect[10, 1: 4] = np.array([7, 8, 13])
connect[11, 1: 4] = np.array([8, 9, 14])
connect[12, 1: 4] = np.array([5, 11, 10])
connect[13, 1: 4] = np.array([6, 12, 11])
connect[14, 1: 4] = np.array([7, 13, 12])
connect[15, 1: 4] = np.array([8, 14, 13])
connect[16, 1: 4] = np.array([10, 11, 16])
connect[17, 1: 4] = np.array([11, 12, 17])
connect[18, 1: 4] = np.array([12, 13, 18])
connect[19, 1: 4] = np.array([12, 14, 19])
connect[20, 1: 4] = np.array([10, 16, 15])
connect[21, 1: 4] = np.array([11, 17, 16])
connect[22, 1: 4] = np.array([12, 18, 17])
connect[23, 1: 4] = np.array([13, 19, 18])
connect[24, 1: 4] = np.array([15, 16, 21])
connect[25, 1: 4] = np.array([16, 17, 22])
connect[26, 1: 4] = np.array([17, 18, 23])
connect[27, 1: 4] = np.array([18, 19, 24])
connect[28, 1: 4] = np.array([15, 21, 20])
connect[29, 1: 4] = np.array([16, 22, 21])
connect[30, 1: 4] = np.array([17, 23, 22])
connect[31, 1: 4] = np.array([18, 24, 23])
#---

pressao = np.zeros((nnodes, ntimes))
for col in range(ntimes):
    pressao[:, col] = col*np.ones((nnodes))

vertices = list()
for elemento in range(nelements):
    nodes = connect[elemento, 1: 4]
    vertices.append(list(zip(coord[nodes, 1], coord[nodes, 2])))

pi      = pressao[:, 1]
colecao = PolyCollection(vertices, array = pi, edgecolors = 'b')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_collection(colecao)
ax.autoscale_view()
fig.colorbar(colecao, ax = ax)
plt.show()
```

Is there anyway that I can make it simple, as it is in Matlab:

```
% Some initialization     
function framei = plotSolutionTimeVar(p, coord, connect, t0, tf, freq, fn)

niter    = round(fn);
t        = linspace(t0, tf, niter);
nel      = size(connect, 1);
timestep = 1.0/freq;

for ii = 1: niter
    for el = 1: nel
        nodes = connect(el, 2: end);
        xx    = coord(nodes, 2);
        yy    = coord(nodes, 3);
        pp    = p(nodes, ii);
        patch(xx, yy, pp)
    end
    framei(ii) = getframe;
end

end

movie(framei)
```

Can anyone here, please, give me some direction on how can I create the animated plot function?

Thank you all in advance,

Comment: What **is** your problem? There are a lot of examples for animations out there. I cannot imagine that none can help you. In any case you should mention which example did not help you and state the reason. You should also be much clearer about what your desired plot should look like and how this is related to `values[i,j]`. (You're having a 2D grid, but if `j` is the timestep the plot would only be 1D?).

Comment: I thought I was clear, but anyway, just edited the post.